# Notes/Domino : C API Applications

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I'd like to build a small Domino addin DLL by Notes C APIs. However it looks like no ND 10/11 C API toolkits are available. So, my questions is... When I build a DLL in ND9 env, the dll also works fine in ND 10/11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HCL has stated that they are working on a C-API update for v11/v12. No word on when it will be available, though

Comment: You might want to check Daniel Nashed's blog for info periodically. He has always done a great job of keeping up with the Notes API version and compiler issues.  https://blog.nashcom.de/nashcomblog.nsf/